# InverseFunction fails at some parameter

Tags: special-functions, parametric-functions, inverse, inverse-function

Currently, I am faced with the difficulty of evaluating the inverse of the function below for certain negative decimal values of the parameter `q`. Specifically for large values of the argument of `rho`, the inversion blows up. My code reads:

```
q = -5/2;
b0 = 1;
rho[r_] := (2 b0)/(1 - q) Sqrt[1 - (b0/r)^(1 - q)]
    Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, (q - 2)/(q - 1), 3/2, 1 - (b0/r)^(1 - q)];
ry = N@InverseFunction[rho[#] &];
```

```
ry[300] // N
During evaluation of In[13]:= Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0. encountered.
During evaluation of In[13]:= Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0.^1. encountered.
Out[13]= ComplexInfinity
```

This is weird since this does not happen for negative integer values of `q`. The estimated value of `ry[300]` should be around (or near) 300 also. So I guess MMA is having a hard time processing decimal values of the parameter `q`, like possibly it tends to treat small values as effectively zero. Is there something that I am missing here? Any help is much appreciated.

Edited: The original function `rho` can be evaluated at any point `r` including the points that I have difficulty with for the inverse function.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error in MMA 13 (cloud). I obtain 0.0173961 +0.0218141 I as the result.

Comment: Hi @MathX, I am only aware of the branch point at $z=1$ but haven't checked on the discontinuities.

Comment: Hi @MarcoB, hmm that's weird but I am expecting a rough estimate of around 300 for the value. Thanks for the info

Comment: Hi @MathX, I have already checked it and I encounter no problem in evaluating the original function at any point. But thanks for the comment. I will add your point in the original question and clarify that the original function can be evaluated at any point including the points that I have difficulty for the inverse function.

Comment: No that's fine.

Comment: No worries I just want this comment section to be empty for other people. When there are more than a certain amount it doesn't show them and you have to click "show more comments" and some more important ones may go down there.

Comment: `InverseFunction[rho][200]`

Comment: @MarcoB I think the copy/paste of the OP has an issue, where the Hypergeometric2F1 part gets dropped. If you make sure the definition of `rho` includes the hypergeometric function, you get around 300.

Comment: Hi @CarlWoll, so in your case it works for `ry[300]`?

Comment: @CarlWoll I see! Thank you for the clarification. When fixing that issue, then it just works with no errors and returns 300.53

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

**Just see, @CarlWoll has found it hours before!**

***This is a typical example, which confirms, what i always say: Use "SetDelayed" only where neccessary, standard should be "Set". With that strategy, you would have seen the error at once!***

Your definitons of rho[r_] is split to two lines. Omit lhs to see it.

```
(2 b0)/(1 - q) Sqrt[1 - (b0/r)^(1 - q)]
Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, (q - 2)/(q - 1), 3/2, 1 - (b0/r)^(1 - q)]
```

Just delete The "Return" and it is ok.

```
q = -5/2;
b0 = 1;

rho[r_] := (2 b0)/(1 - q) Sqrt[1 - (b0/r)^(1 - q)]    Hypergeometric2F1[
1/2, (q - 2)/(q - 1), 3/2, 1 - (b0/r)^(1 - q)];
ry = N@InverseFunction[rho[#] &];

ry[300] // N

(*   300.53   *)
```

Comment: Hi. I think the problem is with the version/copy of MMA that I have. I still get ComplexInfinity even when I use your answer.